# Submit button disappears when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you fill in the form and click the "Start Earning" button the button disappears!!! It still goes through and goes to the next page so that much works but I have no idea why the button disappears.... Any ideas???

```
    <?php /*** Form begins here ***/ ?>
    <form method="post" action="redirect.php" name="home_sub" accept-charset="utf-8" id="home_sub">
        <div class="form_fields">

            <p><label for="first_name" class="over">First Name:</label>
            <input name="first_name" id="first_name" class="text_input required" type="text" value="" onClick="$('#optinsection').show()" /></p>

            <p><label for="last_name" class="over">Last Name:</label>
            <input name="last_name" id="last_name" class="text_input required" type="text" value="" onClick="$('#optinsection').show()" /></p>

            <p><label for="email" class="over">E-mail:</label>
            <input name="subscriber_email" id="email" class="text_input xverify_email required" type="text" value="" onClick="$('#optinsection').show()" autocomplete="off" /></p>

            <p><label for="custom_Address" class="over">Address:</label>
            <input name="custom_Address" type="text" id="custom_Address" value="" class="text_input" autocomplete="off" /></p>

            <p><label for="custom_City" class="over">City:</label>
            <input name="custom_City" type="text" id="custom_City" value="" class="text_input" autocomplete="off" /></p>

            <p><label class="hidden">Select State</label>
            <select name="custom_State" id="custom_State" class="select_input">
                <option value="">Select State</option>
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
            </select></p>

            <p><label for="custom_ZipCode" class="over">Zip code:</label>
            <input name="custom_ZipCode" type="text" id="custom_ZipCode" class="text_input required" value="" maxlength="5" autocomplete="off" /></p>

            <p><label class="hidden">Birth Month</label>
            <select name="custom_DOBMonth" id="custom_DOBMonth" class="select_input select_month">
                <option value="">Birth Month</option>
                <option value="01">January</option>
                <option value="02">Febuary</option>
            </select>
            <label class="hidden">Birth Day</label>
            <select name="custom_DOBDay" id="custom_DOBDay" class="select_input select_day">
                <option value="">Day</option>
                <?php for($dy=1; $dy<32; $dy++){
                    $sdy = $dy < 10? '0'.$dy: $dy;
                    echo '<option value="'.$sdy.'">'.$dy.'</option>';
                } ?>
            </select>
            <label class="hidden">Birth Year</label>
            <select name="custom_DOB_Year" id="custom_DOB_Year" class="select_input select_year">
                <option value="">Year</option>
                <?php for($yr=2000; $yr>1910; $yr--){
                    echo '<option value="'.$yr.'">'.$yr.'</option>';
                } ?>
            </select></p>

            <p><label class="hidden">Select Gender</label>
            <select name="custom_Gender" id="custom_Gender" class="select_input">
                <option value="">Select Gender</option>
                <option value="M">Male</option>
                <option value="F">Female</option>
            </select></p>

            <p><label for="custom_Phone" class="over">Phone: (xxx-xxx-xxxx)</label>
            <input type="text" name="custom_Phone" id="custom_Phone" class="text_input" value="" /></p>

                <span id="optinsection">

                    <br />
                    <input type="checkbox" name="chk_allinbox" id="chk_allinbox" class="required" value="1"  />
                            By checking this box, you agree to our Terms of Service and Privacy Policy and agree to receive daily newsletters and promotions via email from BestHotSurveys.com.
                    <br /><br />        

        </div>
        <div class="form_button">
            <input type="submit" class="submit" onclick="javascript: return TMG_CheckForClick(); ShowExitPopup=false;" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <?php /*** Form ends here ***/ ?>
```

Comment: Maybe something in the button's `TMG_CheckForClick` function hides it? Who knows, you need to debug the code. Or maybe there's a listener for the form being submitted, and hides the button if all fields are valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the site you provided after submit button is clicked the submit button wrapper div `form_button` is stylized by a `background-image` style.

**Before Button Click :**

```
 <div class="form_button">
     <input type="submit" class="submit" onclick="javascript: return TMG_CheckForClick(); ShowExitPopup=false;">
 </div>
```

**After button click with validation pass :**

```
<div class="form_button" style="background-image: url(http://www.besthotsurveys.com/images/form_bottom_sending.gif);">
     <input type="submit" class="submit" onclick="javascript: return TMG_CheckForClick(); ShowExitPopup=false;" disabled="disabled">
</div>
```

So look onto your `TMG_CheckForClick` for removing that `style` or check the availability of that `image`.

Currently for the image access it throws

> The requested URL /images/form_bottom_sending.gif was not found on
>   this server.

Comment: Thanks! I just made a copy of the button image and renamed it to form_bottom_sending.gif so it doesn't disappear for now. Thanks for the help!